# C++ overload of operator[] not working with template class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript

I have a template class Profile which consists of a std::vector and some functions that I perform on the vector.  I'm trying to use Profile::operator[] to access the vector directly, but I'm getting an error on compile.

Profile

```
template <class T>
class Profile
{
public:
    vector<T> mElements;

    template <class T>
    T& Profile<T>::operator[] (const int index)
    {
        return mElements[index];
    }

    template <class T>
    unsigned int Profile<T>::size ()
    {
        return mElements.size();
    }

    ...
}
```

When I try to use the operator in another portion of my code:

```
Profile<float> oldProfile;
vector<float> shiftedVector (oldProfile.size(), 0.0);
int shift = 3;

for (i=0 ; i<oldProfile.size() ; ++i)
{
    shift++;

    if (shift > oldProfile.size())
    {
        shift = 0;
    }

    shiftedVector[shift] = oldProfile[i];
}
```

When I compile, I get the following error:

- cannot convert 'Profile' to 'float' in assignment

Everything that I've read says that this should work.  The only difference is that I'm using a template class.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your member functions and operators do not need to be templates.

Comment: May I ask what's the purpose of the `Profile` class? It might help me give you a better answer.

Comment: It's being used to compare known arrays against new ones.  The values are the new arrays are manipulated to try to find the best fit with the known arrays.

Comment: As I was thinking about it though, I realized that it would probably be best to just incorporate a shift() function into the Profile class.  That fixed my problem by removing the need for the operator[] function.

Answer (score 3):

I think you simply mean this:

```
template <class T>
class Profile
{
public:
    vector<T> mElements;

    T& operator[](const int index) { return mElements[index]; }

    unsigned int size() { return mElements.size(); }

    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you can solve your whole problem by replacing all that code with a simple line:

```
template<class... Args> using Profile = std::vector<Args...>;
```

With the above line you are creating an *alias* for the `std::vector` template class. This is much less error prone and simpler to use. You'll then be able to use it exactly as you have shown in your code.

If you, instead, want to add functionality to the container, I'd suggest you to implement it with as free function using iterators:

```
template<class Iterator>
void your_algorithm(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    // do something to the elements
}
```

The advantages of this approach are:

- container independent algorithm
- you don't entangle the interface of the container

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above, I have decided to make the shift() function part of the Profile class.  This eliminates the need for overloading operator[] and better encapsulates the details of the Profile class.

Thanks for the help.  Your answers were able to spur me off into a better direction for my class.